# Docker Compose port forwarding works fine on MacOS but not on Linux

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Having following docker compose script

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  flowable-ui:
    image: flowable/flowable-ui
    container_name: flowable-ui
    depends_on:
      - flowable-db
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=8888
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS_NAME=org.postgresql.Driver
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://flowable-db:5432/flowable
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=flowable
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=flowable
    ports:
      - 80:8888

  flowable-db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: flowable-db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=flowable
      - POSTGRES_USER=flowable
      - POSTGRES_DB=flowable
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    command: postgres
```

I can start with `docker-compose up -d` flowable image and it is accessible at http://localhost/flowable-ui in my browser.

Doing exactly the same on my Linux machine causes http://localhost/flowable-ui is not loading, I see that there is something there because the browser tries to access it, but it doesn't happen and I get timeout.

Do I have to set up something additionally on the Linux machine?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to port-forward from 8888 from your container to 80 to your host. On Linux, you'd need elevated permissions to open ports 1-1024.

Try a port >1024. For example

```
services:
  flowable-ui:
  ...
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
```

and then access your app on `http://localhost:8888`.

Comment: Tried with different like 8081:8888 and still the same behaviour. You can see that something is there (at local host:8081/) because when docker is not running I get immediately response that nothings there. But after docker-compose up -d when flowable has started and I try to access localhost:8081 the page is loading but nothing finally loads and ends up with timeout. When using docker without compose I can start and access at localhost. But with docker-compose is as I described.

Comment: Try running `docker-compose up` (without `-d`); check the logs for any oddities and update the question. Also would be good to access the app with browser dev tools  (it's F12 key on Firefox) and check the "console" logs.